# Wordpress navigation not displaying all links and shuffled order

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, navigation

I added two post categories to my menu in Wordpress (recently updated to 4.0). They show up in my footer navigation, but not the navigation in my header. I have assigned the same menu to both the primary navigation and the footer navigation. Also, the navigation in my header is completely messed up with regard to the order of the links. They are not reversed, but completely shuffled.

I checked the source of the theme I'm using and the header and footer both use the same Wordpress function to retrieve the navigation items (`wp_nav_menu()`). I changed the theme to twentyfourteen and the menu is still broken. I tried adding the menu again and assigning it to the two positions in the layout, but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour (after updating to 4.0)? Has anyone found a solution or does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

```
<?php 
    //part of header.php

    // Show Primary Menu?
    $show_primary_menu = of_get_option('primary_menu_id');
    if($show_primary_menu =="yes") {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header_menu_primary', 'menu_class' => 'small-links' ) );
} ?>

<?php
    //part of footer.php

    $show_footer_menu = of_get_option('footer_menu');
    if($show_footer_menu == "yes") {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer_menu', 'menu_class' => 'footer-nav' ) ); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried re-ordering the menu items in your Admin Panel? Try going to Appearance > Menus... You can re-arrange menu items, and manage them there

Comment: Yes, I have reordered them. The order is correct in the footer menu and shuffled in the main menu, despite the fact that they are the same menu in Appearances > Menus

Comment: Have you got any `float`s on the main menu styling that could be changing the order?

Comment: The <li> items are floated left, so this shouldn't change the order. Also, if they were floated right, the order would be reversed but otherwise the same. The current order for the main-menu is: 
About Us Contact Gallery Home Maps Resources.
It should be:
Home News Blog Gallery Resources Maps About Us Contact

Comment: You've definitely edited the menu in admin, and saved it? It's clearly not in a random order, it's in alphabetical order

Comment: I actually created the whole menu again and assigned it to the two positions in the layout (by checking the two relevant positions at the bottom of the menu in the admin panel and leaving the irrelevant one unchecked). One of them renders as it should and the other doesn't. To be sure, I changed the order of the menu and saved it. The menu in the footer changes correctly but the menu in the header doesn't.

Comment: Can you give us any code? Like the call to the menu in your functions file, and the point in your template where you get the menu?

Comment: I added the code from footer.php and header.php. In the theme's function.php there was nothing concerning the navigation.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to suggest. Ive upgraded Wordpress sites to 4.0 and never had to touch the menu settings.